# Not sure about the next step in "Getting Started With Python on Heroku"

Tags: python, git, heroku, gitignore

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python

I'm trying to store my app in Git, but I'm not sure how to proceed with the first part:

```
    venv
    *.pyc
```

Where do I type this? What do I have to download (If I have to download anything)?

How exactly do I proceed with this step?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't run this in the shell — you add it to your `.gitignore` file.

If you *do* want to run something at the shell, you can add it like this:

```
$ cat > .gitignore
venv
*.pyc
<press ctrl-d>
$
```

Comment: No problem! At some point, if you haven't already, please give my answer an upvote (presuming it was helpful :) ), and click the "accept" checkmark next to the voting arrows to mark the question as "answered".

Comment: Ah! Well, you should still be able to accept the answer — that will also give you a couple of rep.